# http error 405 with mobile flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, iis-7, actionscript, flex4.5, flex4.6

i am having an issue everytime i try to upload an image from a flex mobile application to an IIS directory and this directory is configerd to be web application
i get an HTTP error 405 'method not allowed'
 hence i dont use any script from the server side and i dont want to use any ..

and the code for the upload button is

```
        protected function getImage(event:Event):void
        {
            var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);
            bitmapData = image.bitmapData;

            byte = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);   // bytearray

            uploadrequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/ProblmeImages/");

            var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
            uploadrequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
            uploadrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.PUT;
            uploadrequest.data = byte;


            urlloader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            urlloader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,uploaded);
            urlloader1.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,displayerror); 
            urlloader1.load(uploadrequest);
        }



        protected function uploaded(event:Event):void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(Alert);
            errormsg = "Done!";
            var str:String = urlloader1.data;
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(Alert,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(Alert);
        }

        protected function displayerror(event:Event):void
        {
            errormsg = httpresponsemsg;
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(Alert,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(Alert);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a crossdomain.xml on the server ?

Comment: could you explain what is crossdomain.xml file

Comment: The crossdomain.xml is a file which defines, who may load/send content to a webserver using flash. More information can be found here http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html 

I mention this because I had problems in the past with PUT withou load  the cross domain.xml manually

Comment: well i tried the crossdomain.xml file and i get the same error 405

Comment: well i reached the solution ... there must be some kind of a script or code from the server side to handle the upload
so with some edit to the flex code and a simple asp.net code i succeded in uploading an image with flash

Comment: var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);
  bitmapData = image.bitmapData;
  byte = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
 
  var base64byte:String;
  base64byte = Base64.encodeByteArray(byte);
  
  var urlvar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
  urlvar.imageData = base64byte;

  uploadrequest = new URLRequest(Connection.GetBaseURL() + "Images/UploadImagees.aspx");
  uploadrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  uploadrequest.data = urlvar;
   
  urlloader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;